# How do I remove a file I accidentally created named $file?

Tags: filenames, rm, special-characters

I was working on a shell script and I accidentally created a file with the variable as its name. Now I have `$file` in my `ls` output, and cannot remove it.  What can I do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can escape the `$` with `\`:

```
rm \$file
```

Comment: Maybe add a comment about escaping special characters?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to use the `-i` switch (interactive, so you are prompted before the final removal) in this case...

Answer (score 6):

You can also do

```
rm '$file'
```

Stuff in single quotes is taken as literal always,so globs and variables don't get expanded.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, if you want to do things literal with these weird characters, you need to escape it.  In a shell there are several ways to do that.  The first one is to prepend a '\' to every character you want to escape.  So you can do `rm \$file`.  Another way is to quote them with single quotes, for example, `rm '$file'` or `rm '$'file`.  Some people also consider double quotes as a mean to "escape", but it only escapes white spaces.  For example if you have a file named `a file`, you can do

```
rm a\ file
```

or

```
rm 'a file'
```

or

```
rm "a file"
```

Comment: `"..."` doesn't only escape white space, it escapes all but backslash, `$`, `\`` and `"` itself (and possibly `!` if history expansion is not enabled. Note that backslash doesn't escape the newline character, it removes it instead (serves as *line continuation*)

Answer (score 4):

If you ever accidentally create a file named `-rf`, you can use `rm -- -rf` to delete it.

Comment: This seems scary to try to test. :-)

Comment: @Peter Grill: This is exactly why the `--` option was created; to remove files that would otherwise be taken as options. Alternatively, you could test it with a brand-new directory named '-rf': `rm -- -rf` should give you an error about being a directory.

Comment: Hmm... what about files named `--`...? Ah, no problem: `rm -- --`

Answer (score 0):

Any graphical file manager should be able to handle this through the context menu, because it doesn't try to interpret anything.

Comment: Or, equivalently, you could hire a sysadmin to do it, right?  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Some ways to get rid of files with weird names are to use globbing (i.e., `rm ?file` if the first character is something strange, but that would also nuke `Xfile`, need to be careful not to match too much, check with `echo` beforehand) and/or use the interactive flag: `rm -i *file` will ask for all stuff called *something*`file` if you want to delete it.